# Grade 12 Math foundations in Probability

Tags: probability

Marco estimates that the probability he will pass Math is 87% and the probability that he will pass English is 73%.  Determine the probability that Marco will:
a)Pass both Math and English
b)Pass Math, but not English
c)Pass at least one of the subjects

I don't even know where to begin with this question.

Comment: Begin by identifying what you know, and what you need to find.  Then think about how you might get there, and what you may need to assume.

Answer (score 0):

This question is demonstrating the property of independent events, that the probability of both happening is the product of the individual probabilities.

So the answer to (a) is $.87\cdot .73$ which is about 64%.

Since the probability of failing Englsh is $1-0.73 = 0.27$ the answer to (a) is $.87\cdot .27$ which is about 22%.

Finally, the way to figure the probability of passing at least one is to note that for that **not** to happen, you would have to fail both, which is $$.13\cdot .27$  or a bit more than 3%.  SO the probability of passing at least one is a bit less than 97%.

Of course, all of this assumes the events are independent, and that might not be the case.  For example, if each course needs 20 hours of studying before the final and you have only 25 hours left, you can't pass both...

Answer (score 0):

To approach this question, you must first break down what it asks, and what it provides. (I am elaborating on what Graham Kemp said).

It says that the probability of passing Math is $\frac{87}{100}$ and English is $\frac{73}{100}$.

This means that out of a 100 tries on his math and english paper, Marco passes 87 and 73 times respectively.

You are asked to find the probability that Marco passes both papers. this means that you need to figure out the probability of Marco passing Math **AND** English.

From the information given, it is clear that passing one paper does not affect the result of the other. Thus the two 'events' are independent. This simplifies things as the event's probability becomes:

$$ P(A \cap B) = P(A) \cdot P(B) $$
$$ P(A \cap B) = \frac{87}{100} \cdot \frac{73}{100}$$
$$ P(A \cap B) = 0.6351 \approx 0.64 $$

For the next part:

$$ P(A \cap B') = P(A) \cdot P(B') $$

The $B'$ means the probability of it **NOT** occuring. This is the same as saying $ 1 - P(B)$.

Thus:

$$ P(A \cap B') = P(A) \cdot (1 - P(B)) $$
$$ P(A \cap B') = 0.87 \cdot (1 - 0.73) $$
$$ P(A \cap B') = 0.87 \cdot 0.27 $$
$$ P(A \cap B') = 0.2349 \approx 0.23 $$

Finally, passing either means that he cannot fail both.

Thus:

$$ P(A' \cap B') = P(A') \cdot P(B') $$
$$ P(A' \cap B') = (1-0.87) \cdot (1-0.73) $$
$$ P(A' \cap B') = 0.13 \cdot 0.27 $$
$$ P(A' \cap B') = 0.0351 $$

But we're not done. This is the probability of him failing both. We want the probability of him not failing both.

Thus:

$$ 1 - 0.0351 = 0.9649 \approx 0.96 $$